# Is setting attributes for base composition instances possible in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, composition

So, I have been reading about composition in Python, and am wondering if there is a way to integrate setting the "base objects" attributes without referring specifically to the "base class" (as is done in the commented out portions of the below code.

So, I am looking for the code snipped below to print:

```
1
2    
3    
4
Success
```

But, with this snippet I am generating a RecursionError.

Is there a way (other than self.a.x = n) to update class A's attribute so that it will be shared with other composed classes (class C in this example)?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.y = 2
        print(self.x)
        print(self.y)
        self.x = 3  
        # would work if "self.a.x = 3"
        # and "__setattr__" commented out

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.a, attr)

    # setattr would have to be commented out here too
    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        setattr(self.a, attr, val)

class C:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        print(self.x)
        self.x = 4
        print(self.x)
        try:
            print(self.y)
        except AttributeError:
            print('Sucess')

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.a, attr)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        setattr(self.a, attr, val)

a = A()
b = B(a)
c = C(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you need to filter that variable out.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.x = 2
        self.y = 3  

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.a, attr)

    # setattr would have to be commented out here too
    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        if attr != "a":
            setattr(self.a, attr, val)
        else:
            super().__setattr__(attr, val)

a = A()
b = B(a)
print(a.x)
print(a.y)
```